# Does (sin(1/x))^2 have an improper integral in between -inf and inf

Tags: analysis, improper-integrals, riemann-integration

I had an exam a few days ago and one of the questions in it was to decide if f(x) defined below, admits an improper integral in I = ($-\infty,\infty$). I have no idea how to show that f has or hasn't an improper integral on I.

\begin{equation}
    f(x)=\left\lbrace
\begin{array}{ll}
(sin(1/x))^2 & \mbox{if $ x \neq 0$} | \pi /2 & \mbox{if $ x = 0$}
\end{array}
\right\rbrace.
\end{equation}

Comment: Welcome. It does iff $x\mapsto\frac{\sin^2(x)}{x^2}$ does, can you see why?

Comment: @FShrike I'm assuming that it would since |f(x)| is smaller or equal to the function you gave and since that function is integrable then f is as well. However, I still don't see why your function would be integrable. I looked online and you have to use complex numbers which is not something we have seen in this class.

Comment: You don't need complex numbers for this. Try a variable substitution.

Comment: @FShrike Alright so I managed to do the variable substition u = 1/x which transforms my fonction to yours. And then I saw online how to integrate it and it just makes so much more sense. Thanks a lot for the answer. It's a shame that I can't go back to my exam and change my answer now, but at least I understand the problem!!